# is there any way method to pass multiseries data in json as its not working normal way in anychart in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, anychart

I am trying to implement a column chart using AnyChart in react and I am passing multi-series data in JSON but it's not working below is a simple JSON structure I need to know how to pass multi-series data in react.

```
const complexSettings = {
  width: 800,
  height: 600,
  type: "column",
  data: "P1,5\nP2,3\nP3,6\nP4,4",
  title: "Column chart",
  yAxis: [
    1,
    {
      orientation: "right",
      enabled: true,
      labels: {
        format: "{%Value}{decimalPoint:\\,}",
        fontColor: "red",
      },
    },
  ],
  legend: {
    background: "lightgreen 0.4",
    padding: 0,
  },
  lineMarker: {
    value: 4.5,
  },
};

const Demo = () => {
  return (
    <AnyChart id="sampleData" width={500} height={400} {...complexSettings} />
  );
};

export default Demo;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this particular format doesn't support multiseries data. For this purpose we recommend using other approaches:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import AnyChart from '../../dist/anychart-react.min.js'
import anychart from 'anychart'

const data = anychart.data.set([
  ['p1', 5, 4],
  ['p2', 6, 2],
  ['p3', 3, 7],
  ['p4', 1, 5]
]);

// Render chart with settings
ReactDOM.render(<AnyChart type="column" title="Multicolumn chart" width={800} height={600} legend={true} />, document.getElementById('root'));
// Re-render with multicolumn data. No need to set type secondly, because it just updates data
ReactDOM.render(<AnyChart data={data}/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Or using instance field, which is the most flexible way of using the plugin:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import AnyChart from '../../dist/anychart-react.min.js'
import anychart from 'anychart'

  const data = anychart.data.set([
    ['p1', 5, 4],
    ['p2', 6, 2],
    ['p3', 3, 7],
    ['p4', 1, 5]
  ]);

  var mapping1 = data.mapAs({x: 0, value: 1});
  var mapping2 = data.mapAs({x: 0, value: 2});

  const chart = anychart.column();

  chart.column(mapping1);
  chart.column(mapping2);

ReactDOM.render(
  <AnyChart
    width={800}
    height={600}
    instance={chart}
    title="Stock demo"
  />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

For details, check samples on [the plugin page](https://www.anychart.com/ru/technical-integrations/samples/react-charts/).